# GitHub Pages não encontra a minha fonte no repositório

Tags: url, css-font-face, github

Enviei um site para o GitHub Pages junto com algumas fontes que serão usadas na página. A estrutura do diretório é essa:

```
MeuRepositorio/
    index.html
    public/
        ...
        fonts/
            MinhaFonte.TTF
        css/
            style.css
```

Dentro do arquivo `style.css`, eu utilizo o código abaixo para importar a fonte:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MinhaFonte;
  src: url(../fonts/MinhaFonte.TTF);
}
```

O problema é que o GitHub Pages não encontra o arquivo e gera o seguinte erro:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

E esse erro é bem estranho pois, se eu passar o cursor em cima do nome da fonte que deveria ser carregada — `MinhaFonte.TTF:1` — ao lado da mensagem de erro, ele mostra a URL completa e **supostamente** correta, que é essa:

```
https://myName.github.io/MeuRepositorio/public/fonts/minhaFonte.TTF
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Não está funcionando, nem a URL relativa e nem mesmo a absoluta. Dá uma olhada por favor no meu repositório: https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/JeanExtreme002

Comment: @AugustoVasques Não. Eu não estou entendendo isso. Se eu digitar na barra do navegador a URL absoluta `https://jeanextreme002.github.io/JeanExtreme002/public/fonts/AutumnRegular.ttf` a fonte é carregada e baixada corretamente, mas dentro do meu site isso não acontece. O que eu faço então?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu tentei utilizar essa URL absoluta com o `raw` e o seguinte erro é gerado: Access to font at 'https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/JeanExtreme002/blob/main/public/fonts/DeathRattleBB.ttf' from origin 'https://jeanextreme002.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: E eu pesquisei no repositório pelo `JeanExtreme002/raw/main` e ele retornou um 404.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, a fonte é carregada e baixada nessa URL, mas apenas se eu colocar isso na barra de endereço. Dentro do site, o erro que eu mostrei lá em cima é gerado.

Comment: Sim, dê uma olhada lá.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, esse é o erro que ele gera...

Comment: Agora eu entendi, tenta `https://jeanextreme002.github.io/JeanExtreme002/public/fonts/AutumnRegular.ttf`

Comment: Foi o que eu tentei na primeira vez, que tu mandou eu colocar a URL absoluta, e não funcionou. Deu erro 404.